# Linux Kernel Threads with semaphore freeze

Tags: c, multithreading, module, kernel, semaphore

I have two kernel threads and I am trying to print from these two threads in alternate fashion. I am using semaphore to sync these two threads.

```
int kthread_1_function(void *data)
{
    while(1)
    {
        down(&lock);
        pr_alert("In Kernel Thread 1!!!\n");
        up(&lock);

        //kthread_should_stop must be used to check if this thread should be stopped
        if(kthread_should_stop())
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Similarly I have one more thread which is named as kthread_2_function. In init module, I create these kernel threads (`kthread_run`) and cleanup_module stop these threads (`kthread_stop`).

Following is my observation on various things I tried.

1. When I insert the module, prints are not alternate. I am assuming this is because by the time thread 2 acquires the lock, thread 1 reacquires the lock and prints again.
2. When I use `msleep(1000)` or `mdelay(1000)` between down and up function calls in both threads I see alternate prints.
3. When I use `msleep(1000)` after up function call in both threads again the prints are not alternate.
4. When I use `mdelay(1000)` after up function call in both threads I see alternate prints but when I remove the module complete system freezes

Can someone please help me understand above observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single semaphore won't give you the interleaving guarantee. You need two semaphores in order to enforce the interleaving. E.g.

```
kthread_1_function:
            down(&lock1);
            pr_alert("In Kernel Thread 1!!!\n");
            up(&lock2);

kthread_2_function:
            down(&lock2);
            pr_alert("In Kernel Thread 2!!!\n");
            up(&lock1);
```

And you need to unblock semaphores before unload the modules to let the threads shutdown gracefully.

Comment: Ok. So lock1 is initialized as UNLOCKED and lock2 is initialized as LOCKED to make this work. Correct?

Comment: Right. Or also it can be vice-versa, depending on which thread you want to be first.

Comment: Ok. This works well with semaphore but kthread and spinlock do go well together.

Comment: @TSP, spinlocks are usually unfair (i.e. threads are not ordered), that means the interleaving is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you Anton. I have posted spinlock related details at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871960/linux-kernel-threads-with-spinlock-freeze.

Comment: Ah, if you use two locks as I proposed for semaphores, it works as well.

Comment: No it actually freezes. After spin_unlock add an msleep of 100 in one thread and 1000 in another and try to remove the module. If I give same value in both threads I see it working. But if they are different they freeze.